# Rails/jQuery plugin for showing personal/presentation cards

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, plugins

I have a Rails (2.3.8) webapp that needs to have the ability to list your contacts in form of "personal/presentation cards".

The "cards" have to be dinamycally generated from DB data (including common personal info plus a little avatar image). I can make the div that represent a card, but then I need some plugin to make them like cards. You can scroll between small versions of the cards and when you click one, you get the fullsized version of it.

I don't have much more requirements than those, I'm open to all suggestions, but it has to be free of course.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up doing it with divs and using some jquery plugin to scroll between them and get the fullsize.